# ASP.Net MVC: Why only selected value is getting passed to action when form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get control over it.just see the view and controller code

```
<form id='your-form' action='@Url.Action("Action","Controller")' method='post'>
     <b>Gender</b><br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Male' /> Male <br />
     <input type='radio' name='gender' value='Female' /> Female <br />
     <hr />
     <b>Hobbies</b><br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Reading' /> Reading <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Sports' /> Sports <br />
     <input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='Movies' /> Movies <br />
     <input type='submit' value='Update Profile' />
</form>

public class HomeController : Controller
{  
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string gender, string[] hobbies)
        {
            // Example output 
            var output = String.Format("The user's gender is <b>{0}</b> and they enjoy <b>{1}</b>", gender, String.Join(",", hobbies));
            return Content(output);
        }
}
```

just see and tell me when user select one or two hobbies out of 3 then why only selected hobbies is getting post back to action method and will stored in hobbies array.

why not all hobbies is getting posted to action with selected hobbies indication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecked checkboxes (and radio buttons) do not post back a value because they are not considered [Successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

And in your case it would not make sense to do so since if they did, `string[] hobbies` would contain an array of all hobbies and you would have no way of determining which ones the user selected.

Comment: do not understand what u r trying to say...."string[] hobbies would contain an array of all hobbies and you would have no way of determining which ones the user selected"  when form post back server then i saw only selected hobbies posted in array. tell me what u try to say?

Comment: I'm saying that if all values were posted back, then how would you possibly know which one the user selected. A form posts back the value of its controls so if they all posted back then you would just get and array of all values - `["Reading", "Sports", "Movies"]`, so you could never know which ones the user selected. But the fact you accepted the answer you did shows you have a lot to learn (its not even correct - its `gender=Male&hobbies=Reading&hobbies=Movies`)

Comment: if this is not correct `its not even correct - its gender=Male&hobbies=Reading&hobbies=Movies)` so tell me which is correct ? post please correct one.

Comment: I have just said its `gender=Male&hobbies=Reading&hobbies=Movies`. But your question was _why all the values are not posted back_ and its because they are not successful controls as defined in the HTML standards that I linked to.

Answer (score 4):

Because that is how form encoding a form works.  When the browser makes a POST request to your website, the body looks something like this:

```
gender=Male&hobbies=Reading&hobbies=Movies
```

MVC just takes that and shoves it in some variables for you.  You assume that any hobbies that didn't come back in the hobbies array weren't selected.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke said this way value not passed `gender=Male&hobbies=Reading,Movies` rather value pass like `gender=Male&hobbies=Reading&hobbies=Movies` ...........is it true ? i will check definitely.

Comment: @Mou He is correct.  Shows how long it's been since I had to look at a raw post body.  I'll edit that to be correct.